# google glass camera parameter settings

Tags: android-camera, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm working on an app that includes a custom camera application on Glass.  I want to be able to hard-set different camera parameters, but I'm having difficulty figuring out which ones I actually have access to.

I tried calling parameters.flatten() and got a whole bunch of options that I thought I would be able to use, but when I tried testing them, nothing happened.  (For example, when I tried setting the color effect to sepia, the result was still in normal color).  Is there any documentation or code I can look at that will tell me which parameter options I actually have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few open issues on our issue tracker about camera parameters that do not behave as expected:

- [**Issue 302:** GDK: Camera effects not registered or take affect](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=302)
- [**Issue 303:** GDK: Request: Additional camera focus modes (with auto focus)](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=303)
- [**Issue 304:** GDK: Camera scene mode does not register or take affect](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=304)

You may want to follow those so that you can be updated as the GDK evolves.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the link.  So there's no documentation on what parameters will actually have an effect?